# Add-On Dev: Default of PointerProperty changes based on type?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm trying to make sense of something I've noticed while debugging.

When I add a property of `bpy.props.PointerProperty` with `type=bpy.types.Object`, the automatic default value (if nothing is specified for default) always seems to be `None`. Edit note: apparently there is no way to specify a default for pointers.

However, if I add `bpy.props.PointerProperty` with `type=MyPropertyGroup` where MyPropertyGroup is a custom class I derived from `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`, the automatic default is not `None`. Instead, it seems to be an allocated instance of the property group.

Is this normal behavior? As a programmer new to Python, I would expect the default to be `None` for all pointers, regardless of the type. I'm assuming the default is a valid instance for convenience?

If this *is* normal behavior, then is the instance of the property group some type of allocation that I need to delete? Or does that happen automatically?

Lastly, is there any way to define a pointer to a property group that defaults to `None`? Something that can be used to reference variable property groups? When I try to use the `default=` keyword, it reports it as invalid.

Appreciate any information on this

Comment: Don't confuse the PointerProperty with an actual pointer like in C or C++, PointerProperties only exist in Blender. Python is managed and has a garbage collector, there is (usually) no need to deallocate/free manually.

Comment: @rjg: Yeah, I had a feeling it was a Blender specific setup. I don't completely understand how referencing works in python, but is there a way to reference a property group using a non-property variable? I'm trying to process a hierarchy tree, where each object in the tree can override stuff. When they don't override anything, they reference their parent's data. When they do override, they reference their own data. But I'm not sure how to pull this off in Blender-Python (how to reference data without copying it).

Comment: I think the normal behavior of `variable = property_group_var` is to create a reference, rather than copy the data, but I'm not sure I understand why

Comment: If I understand the question right, then this is a basic principle of OOP. When you initialize and object, you create an instance of a class and assign a reference to that object to a variable. The variable itself is just a reference to the object, not the object itself. As such you can pass it into functions and the function can operate on the object or you can assign it to another variable, which will still point to the original object. You will explicitly have to copy the object, if you want to create a new object (or use a function that does). https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: Well, I understand what references are, and how they work. But I'm not solid on Blender/Python referencing - specifically, why some types copy data on assignment while others (like property groups) seem to copy as references. I have a feeling I'm confusing myself because I keep thinking of property group variables as an instance of a class of data, when they are probably more like an iterator for a list. If that's the case, then all assignments in Python copy data, and none of them create a reference. Is that right? Blender is just emulating a reference using some type of lookup?

Comment: No that's not right. The normal case is that it's a reference. For example if you create a list `x = [1, 2, 3]` then assign the list to another variable `a = x` and assign a new value at an index `a[0] = 3`, you've modified the same object that `x` is referencing. Printing the values in the list will give you `[3, 2, 3]` for both variables.

Comment: Wow, okay. So assignment of any complex type will copy a reference by default, but all basic types copy data? If it boils down to that, I think I can keep it straight. Thank you for the help.