# Using custom socket types in node tree - can't assign PointerProperty

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties

I am working on a Blender addon based on the node system. I would like to be able to pass my own custom types through the node tree. Currently I can use the following types: FloatProperty, IntProperty, StringProperty, etc... But I would like to have my own custom type, which would encapsulate a float and keep track of other properties when it is modified.

Here are other posts that can be relevant to this issue:

- [How to assign PointerProperty in Operator through UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162375/how-to-assign-pointerproperty-in-operator-through-ui)
- [PointerProperty to node of material node tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101778/pointerproperty-to-node-of-material-node-tree)
- [Add-On Dev: Default of PointerProperty changes based on type?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154732/add-on-dev-default-of-pointerproperty-changes-based-on-type)

I made a sample code to show you the issue I'm running into:

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Operator
from bpy.props import PointerProperty, FloatProperty


class CustomProperty(PropertyGroup):
    bl_idname = 'CustomProperty'
    bl_label = "Custom Property"

    prop_float: FloatProperty(name="Float")


class VIEW3D_OT_custom_operator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.custom_operator"
    bl_label  = "Custom Operator in View3D"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    prop: PointerProperty(type=CustomProperty)

    def execute(self, context):
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("prop_float = {}".format(self.prop.prop_float))
        self.prop.prop_float = 2.0
        print("prop_float = {}".format(self.prop.prop_float))
        self.prop = PointerProperty(type=CustomProperty) #ERROR here!
        print("prop_float = {}".format(self.prop.prop_float))
        return {"FINISHED"}
    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomProperty)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_custom_operator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_custom_operator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomProperty)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.view3d.custom_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    unregister()
```

Here is the error I get from the python interpreter:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 719, in __setattr__
    return setattr(properties, attr, value)
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "prop" from "VIEW3D_OT_custom_operator" is read-only
```

It tells me that I can't assign anything to the property. Maybe it's because I'm assigning the full PointerProperty and I should rather just assign an instance of the object that is pointed by the pointer. However, I didn't even managed to create an instance of CustomProperty by myself. I wanted to look at the code of PointerProperty to look at its implementation and it's implemented directly in C so it's difficult to figure out what the problem is.

In the end my problem is simply that I want to use a custom type in the Node Tree. Do you know how to make it work? Do you have any suggestion on a workaround that would give me the functionality I need?

Comment: `self.prop` is an instance of the "CustomProperty" property group.  Basically `Bar.foo = bpy.props.FooProperty()` is  blender wiring up a blender-centric property on a class akin to `Bar.foo = property(setter, getter)`